# Can comparison operator be defaulted outside of class definition in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, comparison-operators

Starting from C++20, the compiler can automatically generate comparison operators for user classes by means of `operator ==() = default` syntax. But must this operator be defaulted only inside the class definition or can it be after the class definition as well?

Consider the program:

```
struct A { friend bool operator==(A,A); };
bool operator==(A,A) = default;
```

It is accepted by GCC, but rejected by Clang with the error:

```
error: equality comparison operator can only be defaulted in a class definition
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KboK7frhb

Which compiler is right here?

Putting operator definition outside of class definition can be useful for having the operator only in one translation unit, for example, thus improving compilation time of big program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[P2085R0](http://wg21.link/P2085R0) removed the requirement on the defaulted comparison operator to be defaulted on the first declaration. Clang currently doesn't support this proposal:[image: https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html]

See also https://reviews.llvm.org/D103929

Comment: As of clang 14, clang has now added support for P2085R0.